# Determining the coefficients of a binary LFSR

Tags: lfsr

I am currently leaning about LFSRs.

I was told that a binary LFSR with length m has a form of $s_m=a_0s_0+a_1s_1+\ldots+a_{m-1}s_{m-1}$ are binary numbers.

$a_0\ldots a_{m-1}$ are hidden and we are given the output stream of bits $(01101010\ldots)$

How can I determine the coefficients from the given output stream?
Would I need a system of equations?

Comment: HINT: [Berlekamp-Massey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp–Massey_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

I guess $s_m=a_0s_0+a_1s_1+\ldots+a_{m-1}s_{m-1}$ is the equation giving the next bit shifted into the state of a [Fibonacci LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register#Fibonacci_LFSRs).

If we care to write the first $k$ bits of the output of the LFSR as a function of the $a_i$ and initial state $s_i$, we'll get a system of $k$ equations with $2m$ unknowns (the $a_i$ and the $s_i$). With $k$ large enough ($k\ge 2m$), solving that system of equation will yield all the unknowns.

Often, the output of a Fibonnaci LFSR is taken to be the bits shifted out of the LFSR, such that we can directly obtain the $s_i$ as the first $m$ bits output by the LFSR (in some order, typically the first output bit is $s_0$, less often $s_{m-1}$). This removes $m$ unknowns, and $m$ equations.

Often, it's chosen $a_i=1$ with $i$ the index of the first bit to fall out of the register (typically $i=0$, less often $i=m-1$), which would be one less unknown. And sometime the $a_i$ are chosen such that their eXclusive OR is $0$ (because that's a necessary condition for an irreducible polynomial), which would be one more equation.

The [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm) is an efficient way to organize the necessary computations. We have [several questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blfsr%5D+Berlekamp+Massey) about it.